# Form field order in Symfony 4 formevent listener

Tags: forms, symfony4

I've been struggling to get this done.  In the docs, there doesn't seem to have any option to order a form field.

So, I have firstname and lastname fields in my form like this:

```
->add('firstname', TextType::class, [
      'required' => true
])
->add('address', TextareaType::class, [
      'required' => true
])
```

Then, I added an event listener like so:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
     $plan = $event->getData();
     $form = $event->getForm();

     if (!$plan->getReferenceId()) {
        $form->add('ref', TextType::class, [
              'label' => 'Reference Number',
              'required' => true,
              // position should be after the firstname and before address
        ]);
     }
}
```

In some of the threads, there was a 'position' attribute that you can add but that was for Symfony 2 and that doesn't exist now in S4.

I guess this can be done in twig form_widget but I am using twig templates which is used in other forms as well.  So I am hoping to get this done in the formtype if possible.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be a really required issue on Symfony github
here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5827
and here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/11241#issuecomment-288462731 where Fabien personaly declined the possible solution on PR

i have the same problem and it seems that the only solution is order the fields manually printing them with form_row or form_widget one by one on the templates.
like this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html